# Adblock not working in Chrome, recently upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

Adblock is not blocking ads on youtube. If I move to another tab, the youtube screen goes black and I have to reload the page. I don't know if this is an issue with 13.10, but this just started happening since I upgraded. I was using Ubuntu 10.04 and never had this issue. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it happening in normal mode rt only in incognito?  I had a similar problem with incognito and found that if I opened in normal mode first and allowed adblock plus to load before opening incognito, it worked fine.